# About worshipping Gods with mentally concieved offerings

Tags: gods, worship, devi, goddess, puja

The Laliopakhyaana contains the following statement -

> 84-87a. If one cannot afford, one should always worship Ambikā with
> articles mentally conceived and imagined.

**- Lalitopakhyana Chapter 43**

So my Question is.... Is this kind of worship of God using nothing but mentally conceieved articles And accessories actually possible? If yes, What are the recommended do's and don'ts for this sort of worship? And are there other scriptures too which have similar statements permitting one to worship Gods with mentally conceived offerings?

Comment: It is said inexpensive material offerings.. a phalam, pushpam or thoyam needed but not merely an ooha.